# How to run tasks for roles I would select with limit?

Tags: ansible, ansible-role

In my playbook I have:

```
roles:
  - role: role_1
  - role: role_2
```

In my roles directory structure I have defined vars with different values under role_1 and role_2

When invoking the playbook, I am trying to ask it to only consider the role I am interested in at the moment, by using limit:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts.yml  myplaybook.yml --limit role_1
```

What I expect:
It will disregard the variable values under role_2, because I asked it to limit to role_1
What I get:
role_2 variables values override role_1, because role_2 is lexicographically later. ugh!

What else I tried:
I tried to use tags:

```
roles:
  - role: role_1
    tags: [ role_1_tag ]
  - role: role_2
    tags: [ role_2_tag ]
```

Result is still the undesired

Edit: After following the first answer

The syntax for include_role as given here (and in the documentation) does not work without modifications. In the end I made this:

```
tasks:
  - name: include role_1
    include_role:
      name: role1
      apply:
        tags:
          - role_1_tag
    tags: always

  - name: include role_2
    include_role:
      name: role_2
      apply:
        tags:
          - role_2_tag
    tags: always
```

But even then, When I run it, nothing is executed. I run it like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts.yml % --limit role_1 -t role_1_tag
```

Trying another way:

```
tags: always
tasks:
  - name: include role_1
    include_role:
      name: role1
      apply:
        tags:
          - role_1_tag


  - name: include role_2
    include_role:
      name: role_2
      apply:
        tags:
          - role_2_tag
```

Ansible tries to proceed with the other tasks, but without accessing any of the vars under the role, resulting in variable not found error

Since I put the `tags:` outside of tasks I guessed the tags need to be mentioned for every task. Even doing that, I got the same result, which is:

```
fatal: [host_group]: FAILED! => {"msg": "'my_vars' is undefined"}
```

Edit2: Using `public: yes` seems to get Ansible to read the vars, however, again, it reads them all, and `--limit` has no effect

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Only consider the role I am interested in at the moment."*

A: Use [include_role](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_role_module.html#include-role-load-and-execute-a-role). For example

```
- include_role:
    name: role_1
- include_role:
    name: role_2
```

By default, the parameter *public* is *no*

> This option dictates whether the role's vars and defaults are exposed to the playbook. If set to yes the variables will be available to tasks following the include_role task. **This functionality differs from standard variable exposure for roles listed under the roles header or import_role as they are exposed at playbook parsing time**, and available to earlier roles and tasks as well.

---

Notes

- `--limit` select hosts to an additional pattern.
- *apply tags* is not properly described in the documentation. See 
  [include_role with apply tags does not work #52063](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/52063)